# Align Paragraph with the icon using CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have created a simple paragraph with heading, content and a icon in it. i have written the following HTML and CSS for the same

```css
.landing-page-card {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
}
.card-heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.card-subheading {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.card-icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.card-content {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.card-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="landing-page-card">
  <h1 class="card-heading">HEADING</h1>
  <h6 class="card-subheading">Sub Heading</h6>
  <div class="card-container">
    <span class="card-icon">icon</span>
    <p class="card-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </br>
  <a href="#" class="card-link" target="_blank">Download Report ></a>
  </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="landing-page-card">
  <h1 class="card-heading">HEADING</h1>
  <div class="card-content">
    <p>There's power in partnering up. With Nielsen's Connected Partner Program you can easily connect your network. Now, you can shift from managing and analyzing data to making smarter, faster decisions. Because when the data and analytics get smarter, everyone wins.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the paragraph to align next to the icon when a icon is present and take up the full width when there is no icon.

**What i need:**
[image]

**What i have now**

[image]

JS fiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Shareer/gaqb7j7w/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: 2 of the answers that add `display: table` or `overflow: hidden` on the text thus creating a column are in fact creating a _Block Formatting Context_ (BFC in short). If you want to go deeper, you can read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) and [TJ Koblentz formerly at Yahoo!](http://www.cssmojo.com/block-formatting-contexts/)

Answer (score 2):

First, there's no such tag as `</br>`

Second.. just add CSS for paragraphs that have the icon as a sibling:

`.card-icon ~ p { margin-left: 50px; }`

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/gaqb7j7w/1/)

Comment: The tags involving "br" the person asking the question meant is probably <br> or <br/> (both are valid syntaxes). Learn more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Answer (score 1):

Just add following css.

```
.card-content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It will set the layout of the `.card-content` element and text will not undergo icon anymore.

```css
.landing-page-card {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  width: 34%;
  float: left;
}

.card-heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.card-subheading {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.card-icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.card-content {
  font-size: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="landing-page-card">
  <h1 class="card-heading">HEADING</h1>
  <h6 class="card-subheading">Sub Heading</h6>
  <div class="card-container">
    <span class="card-icon"> icon       
    </span>
    <p class="card-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </br>
  <a href="#" class="card-link" target="_blank">Download Report  > </a>
  </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="landing-page-card">
  <h1 class="card-heading">HEADING</h1>
  <div class="card-content">
    <p>There's power in partnering up. With Nielsen's Connected Partner Program you can easily connect your network. Now, you can shift from managing and analyzing data to making smarter, faster decisions. Because when the data and analytics get smarter,
      everyone wins.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display:table` property to `.card-content` class

```css
 .landing-page-card{
      margin:10px;
      padding:20px;
      background: #F2F2F2; 
      width:28%;
      float:left;
      }
      .card-heading{
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 24px;
      color: grey;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      }
      .card-subheading{
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 600;
      margin: 0 0 10px 0;
      }
      .card-icon{
      width: 40px;
      height: 30px;
      float: left;
      background: black;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin-right: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 4px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      
      }
      .card-content
      {
      font-size: 13px;
      display:table;
      }
      .card-link{
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      color: grey;
      }
```

```html
  <div class="landing-page-card">
     <h1 class="card-heading">HEADING</h1>
     <h6 class="card-subheading">Sub Heading</h6>
     <div class="card-container">
        <span class="card-icon">    icon                            
        </span>
        <p class="card-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </br>
           <a href="#" class="card-link" target="_blank">Download Report  >                        </a>
       </p>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="landing-page-card">
    <h1 class="card-heading">HEADING</h1>
    <div class="card-content">
       <p>There's power in partnering up. With Nielsen's Connected Partner Program you can easily connect your network. Now, you can shift from managing and analyzing data to making smarter, faster decisions. Because when the data and analytics get smarter, everyone wins.</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex-box`

```
.card-container{
  display:flex;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gaqb7j7w/2/)